# General form of solution of $x$ for this equation?

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for the solution of $x$ in the following equation:

$$a^x+b^x+c^x=k^x$$

where $a,b,c,k\in\mathbb{R}$ are given and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

But I don't know how to follow.

Comment: I highly doubt that you will find any closed-form solutions for arbitrary parameters. Is there any additional information?

Comment: This is an interesting question, because it could generalize the Pythagorean Thereom into arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: @theDoctor:  no, the generalization of Pythagoras keeps the exponent as $2$.  You add one term on the left for each dimension.  For example, in $\Bbb R^4$ the distance from the origin to $(x,y,z,w)$ is $\sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,c,k$ are postitive and $k \gt a,b,c$ there is a unique solution with $x \gt 0$ by the intermediate value theorem.  It is given by $\operatorname{Garmekain(a,b,c,k)}$, a function I just named.  I doubt you will find a nice closed form, but one dimensional root finding will get you there easily.  Any numerical analysis text will have a section on it.